# Date Time Picker value in hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using daterangepicker and created an asp.net webform with help of the following codes

```js
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
              $('#calendar').datetimepicker({
              format: 'L',
              inline: true
          });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<div id="calendar" style="width: 100%"></div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

I wanted to display selected date into asp.net Hidden Field

Comment: Your field is hidden but you want to display the selected date there! Like the field is already hidden, what is the point of displaying the selected value there? Do you want to display or just bind the date value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#calendar').datetimepicker({
        format: 'L',
        inline: true
    });
});

$("#calendar").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    alert(e.date);
    $('#HiddenField1').val(e.date);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
  <div id="calendar" style="width: 100%"></div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```